# Python can't add canvas to ttk notebook page

Tags: python, tkinter, polygon, ttk, tkinter-canvas

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MainGame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        global canvas
        # ===Part A ===
        self.parent.title('PythonPage')
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        self.page = ttk.Notebook(self, width = 650 ,height = 630)
        self.page1 = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.page.add(self.page1, text = 'Tab1')
        self.page.pack(expand = 1, anchor = 'nw', side = 'top')
        # ===Part B ===            
        canvas = Canvas(self)
        canvas.create_rectangle([10,10, 650,630], fill = 'blue')
        canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        canvas.update()
        self.a = Label(self, text = 'Haha')
        self.a.place(x=50,y=50)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('925x650')
main = MainGame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

How can I add my rectangle into ttk's notebook? I found that my rectangle is always created below the notebook, but this situation is not the same with `Label`.

I want to put the rectangle inside the notebook, should I add something to `self.page1`?.

Comment: If you want the canvas in the notebook, you're going to have to put it _in_ the notebook. Right now it is in `self`, and packed just below the notebook.

Comment: How can I packed it in the notebook? I'm not so sure about how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the canvas to be in the notebook, you must add it to one of the notebook pages. For example, if you want it in `self.page`, you would change this line:

```
canvas = Canvas(self)
```

... to this:

```
canvas = Canvas(self.page1)
```